# mailR package - how to reference dataframe in body of email?

Tags: html, r, email

I am trying to use mailR to reference a character dataframe in the body of an email. I want to include a message such as x = "Today's profit was x" but I am unsure of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One powerful way to do this would be to compile the data frame in a markdown file and the send it in the body of the email.  This method enables you to not only send the data frame but also create a visually appealing graphic around it.

Example code from the [mailR GitHub](https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR):

```
library(knitr)
knit2html("my_report.Rmd", options = "")

send.mail(from = "sender@gmail.com",
          to = c("recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"),
          subject = "HTML file generated using Markdown",
          body = "my_report.html",
          html = TRUE,
          inline = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "gmail_username", passwd = "password", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Reed, however I was looking for something simpler. I was able to figure it out! See below.

```
body = paste("<html> <body><p>",a,"</p>","<p>",b,"</p>","<p>",c,"</p>","<img src=\" ... "> </body> </html>")
```